# unexplicaly shutdown problem and SSH unreachable

Tags: ssh, shutdown, reboot, google-coral

I make this post because I didn't find the answer (I made some searches with tag Shutdown, Reboot and SSH).

Since fews months, I've got 2 Corals (out of 3) that shutdown unexplicaly and then become unreachable.

When this occur, I'm forced to go the device (the serial connectivity doesn't work either and the fan doesn't works at this time), unplug and then re-plug the power in order to be able to reconnect through SSH.

What the best thing to do ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please make sure to boot the board with at least 2.5 amp of power adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar behavior with low power. Be sure you are connecting your board to a 2-3 A power supply. A couple indications that this might be your problem are:

- Your board is connected to your computer USB power
- Your board runs fine until you load it (i.e. start inferencing on the TPU)

That's the first things I would look for.